# Refactoring Angular Coffee code to test it using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, jasmine

There is the following code:

```
  geocoder.geocode { location: location }, (results, status) ->
    $scope.searched = true
    if status is google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK
      $scope.address = results[0].formatted_address
    $scope.$digest()
```

This code works good, but I don't understand how I can test it with Jasmine, because I don't know how to test callbacks. Please, give me advise how to refactor this code in order to test it.